# Why is this code stopping? VB ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, code-behind

Hey I am coding using Visual Studio 2003. My program worked fine until I introduced a dll I made using CreateObject.
Code:

```
Set docs2 = server.CreateObject("DocGetter.Form1")
docs2.GetDocument oXMLDom,numID
```

It appears to be getting stuck at this code. I've already used regasm to register the dll.
What else could be wrong?

Comment: This is a web app, is DocGetter.Form1 an actual form object?

Comment: CreateObject is EVIL!  No place for it in the .Net code.

Answer (score 1):

Add a reference to the dll in your project and instantiate the object like this:

```
Dim docs2 As New DocGetter.Form1()
```

If that doesn't make sense, then fix it so it does.  There's no good reason to use CreateObject in .Net code. (Okay, that's hyperbole.  But the principal is sound).

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify - is this a web app or a client (winform) app? Form1 sounds like a winform. ASP.NET runs at the server, so showing a form would be inappropriate - it would happen at the server, not the client. In short, don't do this!

I also can't see where "stored procedures" figures in this, so I've removed the tag.

What are you trying to do? Options for showing something more complex at the client include:

- dhtml
- flash
- silverlight
- clickonce [requires windows client]
- ocx [not recommended]

Comment: aps.net uses the form paradigm

Comment: @Joel - indeed, but without more context from the OP it is unclear whether this Form1 is a webform or a winform.

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet money that this function isn't defined with this name and/or parameters.

```
docs2.GetDocument oXMLDom,numID
```

But because of the way you're instantiating the object, the compiler has no way of knowing this... I think.